# Wordpress .htaccess file with current system

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay, so I'll explain this to the best of my abilities. I have Wordpress files running from a separate directory "_esSite" in the root folder. To do this, I must update my .htaccess file with some code from Wordpress. HOWEVER, the code in the .htaccess file from Wordpress is now not allowing my real directories open properly because it tries to run it through Wordpresse's index.php. Basically, if the folder/directory actually exist on the server, I want it to ignore the Wordpress code in the .htaccess file. Hope that makes sense.

**Example case:**

If I have a folder on my server named "/xyz/", then I want the htaccess file to basically read everything ABOVE "# BEGIN WordPress" in the htaccess file.

If I enter "/abc/" and the folder doesn't exist, I want it to read everything BELOW the "# BEGIN WordPress".

Please let me know if you have any questions and I'll try to clarify. Below is my current htaccess file.  Thank you very much!

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /_esSite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /_esSite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Can you show your full/absolute server path to WP? I don't understand what the issue is, or even what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay, for example...My website is www.domain.com, but all of the WordPress files are stored in www.domain.com/_esSite/. I used this link (provided from Wordpress) "http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory", but now since I have to modify the www.domain.com/.htaccess file, it's causing my actual directories issues. For example, if I have a directory at www.domain.com/xyz, it's assuming that /xyz/ is a post name because of the Wordpress information in the .htaccess file BUT it's an actual directory, so I need it to look at only the top of the .htaccess.